# Process catching exception

Tags: c#, exception, process

I have a process which starts an .exe which throws exception. Is there a way for the process to catch the exception?

I've tried this so far:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("ConsoleApplication1.exe");
Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
foreach (Type t in types)
{
    MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Main",
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (method != null)
    {
        try
        {
            method.Invoke(null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

but I get an exception on the first line, saying that the .exe can't be found.
I've also tried this:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();

myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\ConsoleApplication1.EXE";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.Start();
```

but when I debug, there isn't any exception, and the ConsoleApplication1.exe doesn't show up.

Comment: I actually don't see the connection between first code block (invoking a method through reflection), and the second one (starting a process), but why don't you use this full path (from the second example) in the first example, and see what happens?

Comment: If you are being told the file cannon be found then your directory path is wrong.  Set the working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the try/catch on the first line of your code and then process the catch.

```
try { Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("ConsoleApplication1.exe"); }
catch { throw; }
```

And otherwise you always could try this:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Where\Your\File\Is.exe";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("ConsoleApplication1.exe")`

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx), which should return the full path